# Find the volume of the region bounded by the planes

Tags: calculus, volume

Find the volume of the region bounded by the planes:

$$8x+7y+6z=5\\y=x,\quad x=0,\quad z=0$$

This is the integral I have set up but it's wrong

$$\int_0^{5/8}\int_x^{\frac{1}{7}(5-8x)}\frac{1}{6}(5-8x-7y)dydx$$

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Everything's correct except that the upper limit of $x$ should be $1/3$ and the volume is $25/756$. The $1/3$ comes from taking $z = 0$ and $y = x$ into $8x+7y+6z=5$.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you!